# Print primary and secondary tabs separately

Tags: theming, routes

I am creating subtheme of bartik theme.

According to page.tpl.php file of Bartik theme it shows that tabs can be printed by following code.

```
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
  <div class="tabs">
    <?php print render($tabs); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above code prints primary and secondary tabs at a single place.

Now i want to print primary and secondary tabs seperately in template file.

Is there any variable which gives me the primary and secondary tabs seperately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I ended up like this:

```
<?php 
  $primary = menu_primary_local_tasks();
?>
<ul class="tabs primary primary-with-secondary clear-block"><?php print render($primary); ?></ul>
```

The above code will return the primary links:

To print the secondary links

```
 if ($secondary = menu_secondary_local_tasks()) {
    $output .= "<ul class=\"tabs secondary clear-block\">\n". $secondary ."</ul>\n";
  }
```

Above code will return the secondary links for the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna set some variables for your page template...

**/themes/YOURTHEME/template.php**

```
function YOURTHEME_process_page(&$vars) {
  // Set local tasks variables
  $vars['primary_local_tasks'] = menu_primary_local_tasks();
  $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = menu_secondary_local_tasks();
}
```

**/themes/YOURTHEME/templates/page.tpl.php**

```
<?php if ($primary_local_tasks || $secondary_local_tasks): ?>
<div id="tasks">
<?php if ($primary_local_tasks): ?>
<ul class="tabs primary"><?php print render($primary_local_tasks); ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($secondary_local_tasks): ?>
<ul class="tabs secondary"><?php print render($secondary_local_tasks); ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your solution is also correct, but i have implemented as below.