# how to properly show MENU LOCAL TASK

Tags: 7, routes

Hoping to get some advises from experts here regarding the Menu Local Task on user/uid/edit page. You see, I'm taking over a project at the brink of death. I have no idea why they hide all the local tasks tab.

I know that showing it on page.tpl.php is as simple as "print $tabs", however the fact that i am using splitting User/uid/edit pages into two (using EditProfile modules) complicates thing a bit.

My objective here is to show that local tasks (View/Edit Profile/Account Settings/Notification Settings) on templates/edit/edit-acct-settings.tpl.php page.

So far I could make that happen by this line on that template page.

```
if ($tabs = render(menu_local_tasks())): print $tabs; endif;
```

But, I'm sure there's a friendlier way to do this.
Again, I have no idea how they made the tabs disappear.

And it came rendered as normal list, not tabs. And I dunno how to exactly theme it if it's the current page. Hoping he "Edit Profile" would go bold or something when I'm on Edit Profile page.

[image: rendered result]

Any advise appreciated. TGIF!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find my solution! This thread here is my saviour: 
[Print primary and secondary tabs separately](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52002/print-primary-and-secondary-tabs-separately)

**In templates/edit/edit-acct-settings.tpl.php page**

```
<?php if ($primary_local_tasks): ?>
<ul class="tabs primary"><?php print render($primary_local_tasks); ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In my_theme/template.php**

```
function mythemename_preprocess_user_profile_form(&$vars) {

  $vars['primary_local_tasks'] = menu_primary_local_tasks();
  $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = menu_secondary_local_tasks();
}
```

Hope this helps any other newbies who encounter same issue!
Thanks all~